# post to facebook link

Tags: facebook, post

I have a game site, and I want to make POST TO Facebook from my game site.

I've looked around and all i can find is that you can share links. 
But I want my button to post something like "**I just killed John Smith in Blahblahland**".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Graph API` and POST a `Post object` to the `feed` connection of the User object.

Or there is `stream.publish` but heard its gonna be depreciated soon.

This link might Help You. [LINK](http://www.terabug.com/publish-site-content-to-facebook-wall-publish-wall-post-publish-stream-js-api-tutorial/)

Comment: The way mentioned in the tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

you nee to look around Open Graph story.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/bestpractices/creating-actions-objects/